# haml indendation inside h5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to use haml but cannot work out how to get this to be inside the header. This works but is obviously not indented correctly because the if/else section is not inside the h5. Every time I try to indent it more it gives me errors re indentation.

```
.inner_page_text_based
  %h5.edit_supplier_header 
    You have a 
    - if @product
      %span{class: "#{@product.name}"}= @product.name
    - else
      %span#package_name
    Listing
```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement shouldn't be indented:

```
%h5.edit_supplier_header 
  You have a 
  - if @product
    %span{class: "#{@product.name}"}= @product.name
  - else
    %span#package_name
  Listing
```

Comment: ok, have edited my original question to reflect what you've said. Now I get an error on the first %span line 'Inconsistent indentation: "  \t  " used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces.' I don't understand why because I'm only using spaces...

Comment: Ok, have resolved the issue. I just deleted all the spaces/new lines and tried again and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Your editor is allowing you to indent some things using a tab and some with a space and HAML doesn't like that - the document has to be all of one or another. If you're using something like SublimeText you can set it to use spaces only, and tabbing in a document actually adds 2 spaces, thereby keeping HAML happy. In the above example, delete all the whitespace in front of the span and then put spaces in to match the indentation above and then try again. Do the same with any other lines it complains about. http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/indentation

Comment: thanks, great advice. I am using sublime. Very helpful